# What happens to votes on GIS Stack Exchange when user removed?

Tags: support, status-completed, votes, user-accounts

I am specifically interested in the case when a 2000+ reputation user chooses to delete their own account, but equally happy to receive Answers dealing with broader examples.

In a Question posed to our Meta community (**[Change vote dropping criteria when a user account is deleted](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/change-vote-dropping-criteria-when-a-user-account-is-deleted)**) there has been discussion about whether a 2,000+ user deleting their account led to loss/gain of reputation by anybody who had received up/down votes from that user.

If a 2,000+ reputation user were to leave **GIS Stack Exchange** today what would happen to the votes cast by that user?

Comment: @AndreSilva technically my question is only about wanting to know what would happen (support) rather than about wanting that to be changed (feature request) but since a change was made during the intervening period I'm happy to mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Votes are revoked when a user deletes their account

Help Center > My Account
How do I delete my account?

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes
>   will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: This could be useful to watch the answer on - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245995/215590